# Kotlin doesn't work with repository unlike service with jdbc

Tags: spring, kotlin, annotations

I have repository class in Kotlin Spring application to which I inject JDBC Template only. Looks like this:

```
@Repository
class MobileRepository(
    private var jdbcTemplate: JdbcTemplate
) {...}
```

It doesn't work throwing `org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException` and suggests that final class may be the reason. Then if I change it to open class it says: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForList(String)" because "this.jdbcTemplate" is null` .

If I replace it with `Component` (or `Service`) annotation (with or without `open` class) like this:

```
@Component
class MobileRepository(
    private var jdbcTemplate: JdbcTemplate
) {...}
```

it works.

I assume the whole code is not necessary, because it works with replacing `Repository` with `Component`/`Service`. What might be the case? Till now I was believing that Repository, Service, Component annotations are basically the same, it's just the semantics. But it turns out that they are sort of not the same.

Comment: That is in fact odd, because as you said, `@Service` and `@Repository` are basically syntactic sugar on the regular `@Component` annotation.

Comment: Does `open class MobileRepository( ` work?

Comment: @dan1st With `@Component` it does, with `@Repository` no, saying that `"this.jdbcTemplate" is null`.

Comment: this is because `jdbcTemplate` is not injected. You can try adding `@Autowired` or use constructor injection.

Comment: On the one hand, I'm using constructor injection (notice the brackets and not curly braces) and it also doesn't work with `@Autowired`. On the other hand, you know from the original question that the same syntax works for `@Component` or `@Service`.